# Not finding proper connections for Django to connect to Neo4j

Tags: python, django, neo4django, neomodel

I am trying to sync Neo4j database with Django, but I am getting the following error:

[image: I am trying to sync Neo4j database with django. But I am getting this error. I am following scholarly GIT page for Neo4django.]

I am following scholarly GIT page for Neo4django.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Please post the database settings together with the error. *Copy* the error here, *not* an image of the error.

Comment: At first sight however, it looks like you have some sort of firewall that prevents making connection.